# Use of "nay" - still current?

Tags: word-usage, formality, humor, literary-english, contemporary-english

I get the sense that the interjection *nay* is seen as outdated and used only for humorous effect.  Is this assumption true, or is it still acceptable in serious writing?

Comment: Are you a native speaker?

Comment: Daniel, 'nay' is typically used in jest but but as the author, you determine the use.  Personally,I would not use it in technical work

Comment: Though *naysayer* is still in common use I think.

Answer (score 1):

As to the meaning of 'no'

## oxford english

> 1. (archaic or dialect) no: nay, I must not think thus.

But it still has another meaning:

> 1. or rather (used to emphasize a more appropriate word than one just used): permission to build the superstore will take months, nay years.

I would look at the context of the writing to determine whether or not it seems 'jocular', as you suggested, but I wouldn't be surprised to find this word used in so-called "serious writing."